# Mutable array, Objective-c, or variable array, c. Any difference in performance?

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, performance, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array (3D matrix) of unknown size, where each element in this matrix is of type `short int`. 
The size of the matrix can be approximated to be around **10 x 10 x 1,000,000**.

As I see it I have two options: Mutable Array (Objective-c) or Variable Array (c).

1. Are there any difference in reading writing to these arrays?
2. How large will these files become when I save to file?

Any advice would be gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Provided you know the size of the array at the point of creation, i.e. you don't need to dynamically change the bounds, then a C array of `short int` with these dimensions will win easily - for reasons such as no encoding of values as objects and direct indexing.
2. If you write the array in binary to a file then it will just be the number of elements multiplied by `sizeof(short int)` without any overhead. If you need to also stored the dimensions that is `3 * sizeof(int)` - 12 or 24 bytes.

Comment: So storing the dimensions would imply 12 times larger file, 200MB vs 2400MB? Why would I want to go with that option, considering the original 3D matrix would(?) be reloaded when I read the binary?

Comment: Apologies I obviously was not clear. Storing the dimensions would take just 12 or 24 bytes. An array in memory, or stored as binary in a file, is just one long list of values; the dimensions are needed to figure out which element in that long list is the value for each (x,y,z) index. Unless these dimensions are fixed you need to store them along with the array - hence 12 or 24 bytes additional storage added to that required for the elements, not much!

Comment: Maybe the section *Multidimensional arrays* in [Array Data Structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure) will explain it better.

Comment: So saving the the matrix to binary file with structure intact would be 200MB + 24bytes? Is this the most space efficient way to save the the matrix?

Comment: @userjuicer - ruling out adding compression, sparse matrix optimisations, etc. then yes.

Answer (score 1):

The mutable array will be slower (albeit not by much) since its built on a C array.  How large will the file be when you save this array?

It will take you more than 10x10x10000000 bytes because you'll have to encode it in a way where you can recall the matrix.  This part is really up to you.  For a 3D array, you'll have to use a special character/format in order to denote a 3D array.  It depends on how you want to do this, but it will take 1 byte for every digit of every number + 1 char for the space you'll put between elements in the same row + (1 NL For every 2nd dimension in your array * n) + (1 other character for 3d values * n *n)

It might be easier to Stick each Row into its own file, and then stick the columns below it like you normally would.  Then in a new file, I would start putting the 3d elements such that each line lines up with the column number of the 2nd dimension.  That's just me though, its up to you.

Comment: Would it be more space efficient if I, in the case above, stored 100 lists as 100 separate files?

Comment: The more files you have the more space it will become.  That being said, doesn't it really matter?  No, we're talking about the overhead of just a file header/file name and such.  Try and make sure that the files are over 4096Kb since usually if you have a file less than this size, the OS will align the file to 4096K (aka, a 2 kb file takes up 4096kb instead).

Comment: Also, I'm assuming you're storing the shorts as characters in a text file.

Comment: Would it really be space saving to store a multidimensional array of short int as short char?

Comment: We're not in the 70s anymore.  If you write them as text files, not only will it be easier to understand the files, but it won't take up 100 megs or anything like that.

Comment: Just how much smaller will the file become if I save it as short char instead of as short int? I was under the impression binary file was the most space saving way.

Comment: A character is binary.  It will take 1 byte to put in an ascii representation of one digit.  so the number 1000 will take 4 bytes: 1 byte for 1, one for 0 and so on.  If you save it in binary, 1000 can be fit into 9 spots, or 2 1/4 of a byte.  But then how do you determine which number is which?  You can place a 0 between them because that's one of your encodings.